# Overlapping communication and computation taking 2.1 times as much time

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, matrix-multiplication, hpc

I've implemented Cannon's algorithm which performs distributed memory tensor-matrix multiplication. During this, I thought it would be clever to hide communication latencies by overlapping computation and communication.

Now I started micro-benchmarking the components i.e. the comm., the comp. and the overlapped comm. and comp., and something funny has come out of it. The overlapped operation is taking *2.1 times* as long as the longest time taking operation. Only sending a single message took 521639 us, only computing on the (same sized) data took 340435 us but the act of overlapping them took 1111500 us.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
// ...
#define COMM_THREAD 0
// ...
#pragma omp parallel
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == COMM_THREAD)
    {
        // perform the comms.
        auto requests = std::array<MPI_Request, 4>{};
        const auto r1 = MPI_Irecv(tens_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_tens_,
            2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);
        const auto s1 = MPI_Isend(tens_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
            target_proc_id_tens_, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1]);
        const auto r2 = MPI_Irecv(mat_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_mat_,
            3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[2]);
        const auto s2 = MPI_Isend(mat_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
            target_proc_id_mat_, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[3]);
        if (MPI_SUCCESS != s1 || MPI_SUCCESS != r1 || MPI_SUCCESS != s2 || MPI_SUCCESS != r2)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("tensor_matrix_mult_mpi_sendrecv_error");
        }
        if (MPI_SUCCESS != MPI_Waitall(requests.size(), requests.data(), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("tensor_matrix_mult_mpi_waitall_error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const auto work_indices = schedule_thread_work(tens_recv_buffer_->get_n1(), 1);
        shared_mem::tensor_matrix_mult(*tens_send_buffer_, *mat_send_buffer_, *result_, work_indices);
    }
}
```

Data from the `tens_send_buffer` and `mat_send_buffer_` is being shared by the `COMM_THREAD` and the computing threads. *But this should only be read-only access since the interfaces take constant pointers/references*!

**Note**: I'm initializing MPI by letting it know that "only the main thread will make MPI calls":

```
auto provided_thread_support = int{-1};
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided_thread_support);
if (provided_thread_support < MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED)
{
    std::cerr << "Fatal error: Multi-threading support not available with the current MPI implementation." << std::endl;
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERR_UNKNOWN);
}
```

**Question**: What *could be* the reason why the overlapped operation is so much slower?

**Information**:

1. The MPI implementation is by Intel as part of OneAPI v2021.6.0.
2. A single compute node has 2 sockets of Intel Xeon Platinum 8168 (2x 24 = 48 cores).
3. SMT is not being made use of i.e. each thread is pinned to a single core.
4. Data is being initialized before each experiment by being mapped to required memory nodes as required by the computation.
5. In the given example, the tensor is sized N=600 i.e. has 600^3 data-points. However, the same behaviour was observed for smaller sizes as well.

**Additional information**:

1. I ran the benchmark for sequential combinations i.e. computation first and communication next, as well as communication first and then computation next - with a barrier between them. The duration is 1564400 us.
2. I ran the overlapped benchmark with *separate* buffers for the computation and communication and still got the same result.

Please excuse the lack of a minimum reproducer because it would mean extracting complex parts from multiple libraries. In view of this, I would appreciate hints and guesses just as well as speculative answers so I can further investigate in that direction.

Further information will gladly be provided upon request. Thanks in advance for your time and thoughts.

Comment: What would the non overlapping program look like? `#pragma omp parallel ... computation` and then communication? if so, does the non overlapping program uses one more thread for computation?

Comment: I will add this information as an edit. As for your second question: the non-overlapping program uses just as many threads for computation.

Comment: 1. Since you're using Intel MPI: there is a bunch of environment variables ruling the comm/comp overlap. Things about using a separate progress thread. See the documentation.

Comment: 2. Traditionally "overlapping comm/comp" is: start isend/irecv; computation ; wait; maybe more computation. That is not what you're doing. Can you arrange your code to conform to that? Just as a data point.

Comment: 3. I don't understand your code. The communition thread communicates the same buffers that the other threads are working on. Are you sure that they have the right data? Are you assuming that the the `tensor_mat_mult` has the data resulting from the overlapped sends/recvs?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The correctness of the algorithm is guaranteed. The sending of the data is preparation for the next step. Indeed, the two operations operate on the same data, but use it in a read-only fashion only.

Comment: Since I'm working in a NUMA environment, I'm using custom scheduling to prevent excessive non-local accesses. So I want COMM_THREAD to be the only progress thread. Does the above code not ensure that?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The problem is that I want to enforce the progress thread in code and not through env. variables: it should be COMM_THREAD.

Comment: I still don't see the correctness. Inside your parallel region 1. the state of those buffer changes because you send/recv/wait on them 2. you use them in other operations. So those operations are ill defined because you don't know if they read the buffers before/after the wait.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Both the sending and the computation use `tens_send_buffer_` in read-only mode. The receiving is done in `tens_recv_buffer_`. In the actual algorithm, for the next step, the two containers are swapped using references. However, that is irrelevant here.

Comment: 1) you should never measure the first iterations as they are generally much slower and include a lot more overheads (so for next iterations to be faster). In fact, the second one is generally a bit slow too but this is fine if you measure at least >10 iterations. 2) Overlapping is hard to do (there are many research paper how much it is) and dependant of the hardware and the MPI implementation. Because of that, I think you should be very precise in results (by showing the time of each operation and each threads) and careful about the experiment due to the many possible biases.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm measuring 50 runs after 10 runs of warm-up which are not timed. I also have the measurements in logs, they seem alright. This is definitely a problem caused by MPI's weird concept of 'progress'.

Comment: AFAIK, using a procession thread is a common method because of the lack of feature in the past from both the hardware and the software stacks (and when it is possible, it is not always efficient because of the way OS was designed so far). In fact, a full offloading of complex collectives can be very difficult to do. Modern MPI implementations tends to let lower-level hardware-related stacks to do that (the one of the NIC that may not even require that or generic dedicated libs like libevent). So the kind of network stack play a role in the resulting performance.

Comment: Your overlap version uses n-1 threads for computation (since the master thread does not compute anything). So does the non overlap version uses n threads or n-1 (e g. the master thread does artificially nothing in order to ensure an apple to apple comparison)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes, my non-overlap versions are exact extractions from this one i.e. always same conditions