# Enforcing progress thread when overlapping communication and computation

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, distributed-computing, hpc

This question is originating from here: [Overlapping communication and computation taking 2.1 times as much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331711/overlapping-communication-and-computation-taking-2-1-times-as-much-time).

I've implemented Cannon's algorithm which performs distributed memory tensor-matrix multiplication. During this, I thought it would be clever to hide communication latencies by overlapping computation and communication.

Now I started micro-benchmarking the components i.e. the communication, the computation and the overlapped communication and computation, and something funny has come out of it. The overlapped operation is taking *2.1 times* as long as the longest time taking operation of the two. Only sending a single message took 521639 us, only computing on the (same sized) data took 340435 us but the act of overlapping them took 1111500 us.

After numerous test-runs involving independent data buffers and valuable inputs in the form of comments, I have come to the conclusion that the problem is being caused by MPI's weird concept of progress.

The following is the desired behaviour:

1. **only** the thread identified by `COMM_THREAD` handles the communication and
2. all the other threads perform the computation.

If the above behaviour can be forced, in the above example, I expect to see the overlapped operation take ~521639 us.

**Information**:

1. The MPI implementation is by Intel as part of OneAPI v2021.6.0.
2. A single compute node has 2 sockets of Intel Xeon Platinum 8168 (2x 24 = 48 cores).
3. SMT is not being made use of i.e. each thread is pinned to a single core.
4. Data is being initialized before each experiment by being mapped to the corresponding memory nodes as required by the computation.
5. Benchmarking runs are preceded by 10 warm-up runs.
6. In the given example, the tensor is sized N=600 i.e. has 600^3 data-points. However, the same behaviour was observed for smaller sizes as well.

**What I've tried**:

1. Just making asynchronous calls in the overlap:

```
// ...
#define COMM_THREAD 0
// ...
#pragma omp parallel
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == COMM_THREAD)
    {
        // perform the comms.
        auto requests = std::array<MPI_Request, 4>{};
        const auto r1 = MPI_Irecv(tens_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_tens_,
            2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);
        const auto s1 = MPI_Isend(tens_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
            target_proc_id_tens_, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1]);
        const auto r2 = MPI_Irecv(mat_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_mat_,
            3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[2]);
        const auto s2 = MPI_Isend(mat_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
            target_proc_id_mat_, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[3]);
        if (MPI_SUCCESS != s1 || MPI_SUCCESS != r1 || MPI_SUCCESS != s2 || MPI_SUCCESS != r2)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("tensor_matrix_mult_mpi_sendrecv_error");
        }
        if (MPI_SUCCESS != MPI_Waitall(requests.size(), requests.data(), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("tensor_matrix_mult_mpi_waitall_error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const auto work_indices = schedule_thread_work(tens_recv_buffer_->get_n1(), 1);
        shared_mem::tensor_matrix_mult(*tens_send_buffer_, *mat_send_buffer_, *result_, work_indices);
    }
}
```

2. Trying manual progression:

```
if (omp_get_thread_num() == COMM_THREAD)
{
    // perform the comms.
    auto requests = std::array<MPI_Request, 4>{};
    const auto r1 = MPI_Irecv(tens_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_tens_,
        2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0]);
    const auto s1 = MPI_Isend(tens_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * tens_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
        target_proc_id_tens_, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1]);
    const auto r2 = MPI_Irecv(mat_recv_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_recv_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE, src_proc_id_mat_,
        3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[2]);
    const auto s2 = MPI_Isend(mat_send_buffer_->data(), 2 * mat_send_buffer_->size(), MPI_DOUBLE,
        target_proc_id_mat_, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[3]);
    if (MPI_SUCCESS != s1 || MPI_SUCCESS != r1 || MPI_SUCCESS != s2 || MPI_SUCCESS != r2)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("tensor_matrix_mult_mpi_sendrecv_error");
    }
    
    // custom wait-all to ensure COMM_THREAD makes progress happen
    auto comm_done = std::array<int, 4>{0, 0, 0, 0};
    auto all_comm_done = false;
    while(!all_comm_done)
    {
        auto open_comms = 0;
        for (auto request_index = std::size_t{}; request_index < requests.size(); ++request_index)
        {
            if (comm_done[request_index])
            {
                continue;
            }
            MPI_Test(&requests[request_index], &comm_done[request_index], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            ++open_comms;
        }
        all_comm_done = open_comms == 0;
    }
}
else
{
    const auto work_indices = schedule_thread_work(tens_recv_buffer_->get_n1(), 1);
    shared_mem::tensor_matrix_mult(*tens_send_buffer_, *mat_send_buffer_, *result_, work_indices);
}
```

3. Using the environment variables mentioned here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference/environment-variables-for-async-progress-control.html in my job-script:

```
export I_MPI_ASYNC_PROGRESS=1 I_MPI_ASYNC_PROGRESS_THREADS=1 I_MPI_ASYNC_PROGRESS_PIN="0"
```

and then running the code in variant 1.

All of the above attempts have resulted in the same undesirable behaviour.

**Question**: How can I force only `COMM_THREAD` to participate in MPI progression?

Any thoughts, suggestions, speculations and ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note**: although the buffers `tens_send_buffer_` and `mat_send_buffer_` are accessed concurrently during the overlap, this is read-only access.

Comment: Did you pin MPI processes to a single socket or less? Did you pin OpenMP threads to cores?

Comment: What you can do is start a timer at the end of the master section and stop it at the end of the openmp section; then you can confirm whether communications (e.g. master) or computations (e.g. non master) are the bottleneck. You can also add `MPI_Barrier()` and time them before and after each iteration to check whether the time is spent in imbalance or pure communications.

Comment: Last not least, you can try to always post `MPI_Irecv()` in advance in order to avoid (as much as possible) unexpected messages (they can cause all kinds of performance issues)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've pinned 48 threads to 48 cores distributed across two sockets using the Slurm pinning tool. As for your other tips, it's not about finding out which is the bottleneck, it's about how the overlapped operation is taking much longer than the longest time taking operation. And that's because Intel MPI is stealing my hardware resources without asking me because of its concept of 'progress'.

Comment: a progress thread basically allows a message to be sent between `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Wait()`. So in your case, you do not want a MPI progress thread since you have your own.

Comment: You should really restrict a MPI task to a socket in order to avoid some undesired NUMA effects. Note SLURM only pins the MPI tasks. You need to tell the OpenMP runtime to pin the OpenMP threads. With Intel MPI `export KMP_AFFINITY=compact,verbose` can do the trick.

Comment: If the root cause of the performance hit is some load imbalance, you really want to know it instead of blaming what you think is Intel MPI concept of progress. FWIW, a simple test is to rebuild your app with Open MPI and see if you observe the same behavior.